# C# removes duplicates in JSON request body

Tags: api, duplicates, odata, deserialization

I've this endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("some\odata\route")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Func_Name(Request_Type request)
{
    ...
}
```

`request` is IDictionary< string, string>. If user calls this endpoint with a JSON containing duplicates:

```
{
    "Bob": "Doctor",
    "Tim": "Engineer",
    "Bob": "Sailor"
}
```

What I see in C# is:

```
{
    "Tim": "Engineer",
    "Bob": "Sailor"
}
```

Means, it always takes the last. How can I stop this automatic removal and see the duplicates after deserialization? Or making the endpoint fail on calls like these?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your parameter of your Post method you can try the following. Otherwise C# will try to automatically map the entity which will lead to an error.

```
var rawJson = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

That will get you the raw JSON which will not be validated and hold the three properties: two of which have the "Bob" key. However I would consider this a bad idea and I'm puzzled by your use case.

C# cannot possibly convert your JSON to a `Dictionary<string, string>` seeing as the Key property of a Dictionary must always be unique. Needless to say that the JSON is also considered invalid when run through a validator.

```
{
    "Bob": "Doctor",
    "Tim": "Engineer",
    "Bob": "Sailor"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to List instead of Dictionary